# When will be Eclipse RCP Application gets hang

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I want to collect the eclipse RCP related logs for all possible scenarios to get application hang. eg "invalid thread access error" while accessing UI thread from the nonUI thread.

Please provide the number of the use case with the snippet.

Comment: Do you mean the _UI Responsiveness Monitoring_ (_Window > Preferences: General > UI Responsiveness Monitoring_) which logs stack traces of UI freezes as errors?

Comment: We have applications in Eclipse RCP, I want to know what are the scenarios application get the hang because of large data or bad coding etc. e.g accessing UI thread from non UI thread will get invalid thread access and application will hang, likewise, I need all use cases where application will hang.

Comment: Basically, I want to freeze my application explicitly and get the logs.

Comment: I can only imagine two cases: long time calculations in the UI thread (which should not be done in the UI thread) and a (dead)locked UI thread (e.g. `synchronized` in the UI thread causing waiting for non-UI threads). To freeze your application do `Thread.sleep(9_999)` in the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks  howlger
I added below code and application freeze but where to get freeze log

syncExec(new Runnable()
        {

            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException e)
                    {
                      
                    }
                }
            }

        });

Comment: What do you exactly mean by _freeze log_? Stack traces of all threads when the UI freezes? Include in your RCP application and enable the _UI Responsiveness Monitoring_ for that.